# Fade the top of the element with CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I create an effect similar to **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRZWn.png)** in CSS (box on the right)?

Small question, but short is sweet.  I'd post code I've tried, but I can't get a start on fading the entire box, which would also suffice for my purposes (I can add another div with the background underneath, all I need is to fade the text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use image masks. This however is only available for pretty much Chrome. **[More info](http://caniuse.com/css-masks)**.

```
element {
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, 
        0 0, 
        0 50%, 
        from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), 
        to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1))
    )
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UULkj/)

Comment: Although Joseph's is more browser compatible, I think I'll go with this one, due to the simplicity of it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use a `linear-gradient` with `rgba`, going from full opacity to 0 with the same color:

```
div {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background: rgb(163, 182, 245);
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

div:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    height: 80px;
    background: linear-gradient(
        rgba(163, 182, 245, 1),
        rgba(163, 182, 245, 0)
    );
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HUHKB/

---

**P.S.** Don't forget the vendor prefixes in production...